# On click anchor tag scroll to div is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On click of "a" tag page should scroll to div that has class called "cmntBox" I have done through jquery but it returning nothing actually when I click Write a review button it should scroll down to div.

HTML code

```
  <a href="" class="ritrvw cmntBox"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Write a review</a>




<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 nopad cmntBox">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-review">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                  <div id="review"></div>
                  <h3>Write a review</h3>
                  <div class="form-group required">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <label class="control-label" for="input-name">Your Name</label>
                      <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group required">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <label class="control-label" for="input-review">Your Review</label>
                      <textarea name="text" rows="5" id="input-review" class="form-control"></textarea>
                      <div class="help-block"><span class="text-danger">Note:</span> HTML is not translated!</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group required">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <label class="control-label">Rating</label>
                      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Bad&nbsp;
                      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" />
                      &nbsp;
                      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" />
                      &nbsp;
                      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" />
                      &nbsp;
                      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" />
                      &nbsp;
                      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" />
                      &nbsp;Good</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group required">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <label class="control-label" for="input-captcha">Enter the code in the box below</label>
                      <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" id="input-captcha" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12"> <img src="index.php?route=tool/captcha" alt="" id="captcha" /> </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="buttons">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                      <button type="button" id="button-review" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Jquery code,

```
  $(".cmntBox").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollBottom: $(".cmntBox").offset().bottom
        }, 2000);
    });
```

Comment: Keep in mind too that your event handler and jquery selector are targeting the link AND the div, you'll want to have a unique class (or ID) to address them each in JS. If you try to scroll to ".cmntBox" that selector matches both the link and the div.

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this code

```
scrollTop:$(".cmntBox").offset().top}, 2000);
```